# Norm of an integral operator

Tags: normed-spaces, integral-operators

I have an exercise that I need to solve and I can't finish it.
Let $k \in \mathcal{C}([0,1] \to \mathbb{R})$.
Proove that this operator :
$$
\begin{array}{ccccc}
T & : & \left(\mathcal{C}([0,1] \to \mathbb{R}), ||.||_\infty \right) &\rightarrow  &  \mathbb{R}\\
 & & f &\mapsto & \int_0^1 k(t)f(t)dt\\
\end{array}
$$
is continuous, calculate its norm.

As this is a linear operator, I've shown that it is bounded by $||k||_1$, which prooves that it's continuous.
Therefore $|||T||| \leq ||k||_1$.
I think that, indeed, $|||T||| = ||k||_1$.

But, I have a problem finding a function $g$ such as $||g||_\infty \leq 1$ and $|T(g)| = ||k||_1$.
I thought about $g(x) = sign(k)$, with this function that would work.
Problem : the function $g$ is not continuous… 
Solution : find a sequence of continuous functions $g_n$ which, starting a certain rank, verifies $\forall n, \ ||g_n||_\infty \leq 1$ and has for limit $g$.
Question : does such a sequence exist ?
If yes, what is its expression ?

Thanks in advance and sorry for my bad english.